# Когда появилось слово ваще/ващще/воще/вощще?

Tags: этимология, лексика, жаргон, историческая-грамматика, историческое-словообразование

По некоторым источникам видно, что слово «ваще» (другие варианты: *воще*, *ващще*, *воще*, *вощще*) уже используется в 1985 г.

Comment: Прошу прощения за любопытство? Почему это важно? Уже второй вопрос тут такого содержания. Не понимаю, почему люди задаются такими вопросами. На мой взгляд, эти слова являются просторечиями от слова «вообще», которое является сокращением от «в общем». Поскольку такие слова является больше устными, чем письменными, трудно найти подтверждения существования их в прошлом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Порылась — чисто *из интересу.*

Начала с Даля:
[вообще́](https://gufo.me/dict/dal/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5), нареч., ***вобще, вопче*** стар. нераздельно, совокупно, вместе, собща; оптом, огулом, повально, не частно, без изъятий; всюду, всегда. *Мы торгуем вообще с ним. Отдавай не враздробь, а вобще.*

Потом просмотрела словарь русских народных говоров, нашла только [вобща́](https://iling.spb.ru/dictionaries/srng/04.pdf) (*нареч.* Вместе; сообща. *Купить бы нам жито-то с тобою вобща.* Арх., 1857; стр. 327).

И только потом обратилась к Нацкорпусу (в поисках самого раннего использования):
*ваще* — 1990;
*вааще* — 1993;
*воще* — Круглолицый товарищ мой, не выдержав бессонных ночей, холодов и стихов, собрался домой. ― Воще-то… собака… натаскивать… Лялька там… дачу снимать… [Юрий Казаков. Долгие крики (1966-1972)] (можно почитать [тут](https://knijky.ru/books/vo-sne-ty-gorko-plakal?page=260));
*вооще* — Вооще же наш барак действительно будет проходным двором. [Б. И. Вронский. Дневник (1961)] (можно почитать [тут](https://prozhito.org/notes?date=1961-01-01&diaries=%5B393%5D&offset=200), 26 июня; возможно, что совсем и не "вооще").